# Lyapunov Exponents for $n$-Dimensional Matrix $A$

Tags: calculus, matrices, chaos-theory, lyapunov-functions, lyapunov-exponents

I am wondering whether my solve is correct. I know how to solve the 2, or 3 dimension of the state matrix. But what if the state matrix goes to n-dim?
Here is what I tried:

To find the Lyapunov exponents for the matrix $A$, where
$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
$
and $a_{ij}$ are real random variables with $\mathbb{E}[\log |a_{ij}|] < \infty$, you can use Oseledet's multiplicative ergodic theorem.

The Lyapunov exponents $\lambda_k$ are defined as:
$
\lambda_k = \lim_{{m \to \infty}} \frac{1}{m} \log \left\| \prod_{{i=1}}^m A_i \right\|,
$
where $A_i$ are the random matrices in the product. In your case, $A_i = A$ for all $i$.

To calculate $\prod_{i=1}^m A_i$, you can compute $A^m$ for any positive integer $m$ using standard matrix multiplication. The expression for $A^m$ will involve $a_{ij}$ raised to the power $m$ in the matrix entries.

After finding $A^m$, you can compute its operator norm, denoted as $\|A^m\|$, which is the maximum singular value of the matrix $A^m$. Finally, you can calculate the Lyapunov exponents using the formula:
$
\lambda_k = \lim_{{m \to \infty}} \frac{1}{m} \log \|A^m\|.
$
Finding a general closed-form expression for the Lyapunov exponents for $n$-dimensional matrices with random entries like $A$ can be quite challenging and may depend on the specific distributions of the $a_{ij}$ entries. The approach involves computing the matrix powers and singular values, which can become increasingly complicated as $n$ grows.
Clarify the question when $m\to n$ of the dimension of the state matrix, how to find an exponent of the matrix above.

You might need to work with specific distributions or assumptions to simplify the calculations.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry I missed some sencences.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question would be what is the difference between $A$ is 2 or 3 dimensions and $A$ is an n-dim state matrix when finding the Lyapunov exponent?

If so, the most regular method is Oseledet's multiplicative ergodic. Let me first use a 2-dim state matrix to show how to adopt this theorem for finding Exponent:

To find the Lyapunov exponents for the given matrix $A$, you can use Oseledet's multiplicative ergodic theorem. First, let's define the matrix $A$ as:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a \\
1 & b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where a and b are real random variables with finite expectations, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[\log |a|] < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[\log |b|] < \infty$.

The Lyapunov exponents are defined as:

$$
\lambda_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \left\| \prod_{i=1}^n A_i \right\|
$$

where $A_i$ are the random matrices in the product. In your case, $A_i = A$ for all $i$, as given. To find the Lyapunov exponents, we need to calculate the product of these matrices and then compute the limit.

Let's calculate $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n A_i = A^n = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a \\
1 & b
\end{bmatrix}^n
$$

And

$
\lambda_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \|A^n\|
$.

Similarity, for $n$-dim matrix,
one can use Oseledet's multiplicative ergodic theorem to find the Lyapunov exponents for the matrix $A$, where
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \ldots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $a_{ij}$ are real random variables with $$\mathbb{E}[\log |a_{ij}|] < \infty$$

The Lyapunov exponents $\lambda_k$ are defined as:
$$
\lambda_k = \lim_{{m \to \infty}} \frac{1}{m} \log \left\| \prod_{{i=1}}^m A_i \right\|,
$$
where $A_i$ are the random matrices in the product. In your case, $A_i = A$ for all $i$.

Remark that when calculating $\prod_{i=1}^m A_i$, the most regular method is to compute $A^m$ for any positive integer $m$ using standard matrix multiplication. The expression for $A^m$ will involve $a_{ij}$ raised to the power $m$ in the matrix entries.

After finding $A^m$, you can compute its operator norm, denoted as $\|A^m\|$, which is the maximum singular value of the matrix $A^m$. Finally, you can calculate the Lyapunov exponents using the formula:
$$
\lambda_k = \lim_{{m \to \infty}} \frac{1}{m} \log \|A^m\|.
$$

Finding a general closed-form expression for the Lyapunov exponents for $n$-dimensional matrices with random entries like $A$ can be quite challenging and may depend on the specific distributions of the $a_{ij}$ entries.